# My hyperlink goes across entire page instead of just the image

Tags: html, css

I have a logo that I want to link back to my home page.  However, when I hyperlink the logo, I notice that the link spans across the entire page (i.e. across the whitespace to the left and right of the logo) instead of just being on the logo image.

My HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="splash-logo">
    <img src="images/splash-logo.png" width="259" height="51">   
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
#splash-logo {
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your CSS shows the width of the element as 100%, so it would take up the whole width of the page. If you're looking to make it the size of the image, set it to 259px instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the width:100%, since it is 100% width, of course it will span across (horizontal) the page

Comment: Not exactly. If the parent of a tag has specified with it'll just fill out that parent, it doesn't necessarily mean it's the 100% of the page.

Comment: Hence I said across and not 100% of the page

Answer (score 1):

Your link's width is the width of the parent tag. Instead of doing 100%, just specify the width of the block.